# MFC Extract CString between tags

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to code a function to retrieve the value between two tags or characters using CStrings, so far I haven't been able to do so.

```
CODE REMOVED
```

I'm pretty sure StartIndex and EndIndex have the right values, however I'm stuck at the last step, where I'm supposed to extract the substring from between the tags.

EDIT:// Got it working, thanks to Igor Tandetnik. If anyone knows why SubStr only prints correctly with wcout if I explicitly cast it with `(LPCWSTR)` it would be greatly appreciated. I'm leaving the working code below in case someone else needs this or wants to improve it.

```
CString ExtractString(CString strSource, CString strStart, CString strEnd)
{
    CString SubStr = L"";
    int iEndIndex, iStartIndex = strSource.Find(strStart);
    iStartIndex += strStart.GetLength();
    iEndIndex = strSource.Find(strEnd, iStartIndex);

    if (iStartIndex == -1 || iEndIndex == -1)
    {
        wcout << L"TAG not found!" << endl;
        return SubStr;
    }

    SubStr = strSource.Mid(iStartIndex, (iEndIndex - iStartIndex));
    SubStr.Trim();
    return SubStr;
}
```

Comment: Define "stuck". What exactly is the nature of the difficulty? What outcome do you observe, what do you expect, and how do the two differ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the Substring between two tags, currently my function is not working properly. When I try to get the Substring (LAT)S 20 58 45        (END), the output should be S 20 58 45        , including the whitespaces. Right now, I'm just getting an hexadecimal value. I checked the indexes StartIndex and EndIndex and they do return the right values, so I assume the problem is in line 6, where I'm trying to extract the Substring. I'm just beginning to program in C++ and I ran out of ideas on what I'm doing wrong, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is, you are building an Ansi (as opposed to Unicode) build. The hex string is the address of the character buffer managed by `SubStr`, because your print statement is essentially `wcout << (char*)SubStr`. In other words, the problem is not with computing the substring, but with the way you print it.

Comment: Thanks for the help Igor, however I am building it with Unicode Character Set. My guess is either something wrong in line 6 or the logic behind it is not correct.

Comment: Does this work? `CString test="ABC"; wcout << test;` That'll tell you whether the problem is with computing the substring, or with printing after all.

Comment: Yeah wcout does work with other CStrings, however you were right, I used AfxMessagebox and I got the right output. For some reason I can't print the same text using wcout, I'm pretty sure it must be a dumb mistake in the way I'm printing it. Any help appreciated. If I try wcout << *Done I get the first character of the string.

Comment: What's `Done`? How is it declared? How does it fit into the picture? In the code you show, it's never declared or assigned a value.

Comment: I'm sorry Done is just a typo from when i pasted my code in here, its supposed to be SubStr. The CString that is initialized as global outside of his function, Text, contains the string from which im trying to extract the substring. I'm printing it with wcout and it looks ok to me.

Comment: Try `wcout << LPCWSTR(SubStr)`. Though I'm not sure why it doesn't work without explicit cast.

Comment: Thanks Igor!, that got it working. However, Im worried that I'm doing something wrong somewhere, i shouldn't have to explicitly cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `std::wstring` to `wcout`, it works fine because those guys know each other. `wcout` will pick the right `<<` operator for `std::wstring`

But C++ Standard Library and MFC are separate. `wcout` doesn't know what to do with `CString`, so it treats `CString` object as `const void*`, it uses `operator<<(const void*)` to print an address.

Next step, `CString` returns (`const wchar_t*`) buffer. But `wcout` had already decided on `const void*`, so `wcout` prints the address of that string buffer returned by `CString`.

`(const wchar_t*)` cast will instruct `wcout` to use the right `<<` operator. You can also use `CString::GetString()` to let `wcout` know that wide characters are being sent.

```
wcout << LPCWSTR(SubStr);
//or
wcout << SubStr.GetString();
```